# How to dump from remote postgres database to a directory inside a docker container?

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, pg-dump

I have a a remote database on `postgresql://postgres:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME`

I have a docker container running named `local_pg_container` that is running using an image of postgres.

I want to dump the remote database inside the local container

I do:

```
$ docker exec local_pg_container pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME -f ~/backup.sql
```

But it is saying that

```
pg_dump: error: could not open output file "/home/MY_HOST_USER/backup.sql": No such file or directory
```

First of all, it seems that it is trying to put the backup file in the host server of the docker container, not inside the container

and secondly, it is saying no such file.

Any solution?

Comment: Assuming you started the database container with a `docker run -p` option or Compose `ports:`, you can use `psql` or `pg_dump` to connect to it, the same way you do the fully-remote database.  You don't need to do anything Docker-specific here.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
docker exec local_pg_container bash -c "pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME -f ~/backup.sql"
```

It can be modified to be piped directly into psql

```
docker exec local_pg_container bash -c "pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://postgres:DB_PASSWORD@DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DB_NAME | psql -U postgres DB_NAME"
```